# Subtract a value from the highest prior value that is within a certain time frame, in r

Tags: r

I am trying to create a difference variable by subtracting each value in a column from the highest value within the three years prior, for each individual id.

My data looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4),
                  testocc = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,4,1,2,3),
                  score = c(0.8,0.3,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.5,0.9,0.5,0.7,0.6,0.3,0.2,0.6),
                  time = c(0,1,1,3,0,4,0,4,2,1,0,3,2))
```

And my desired output looks like this:

```
> data                            Score.Maximum
id   testocc   score   time    Within.3.Years.Prior    Difference (= Score - Score Maximum within 3 Years Prior)
1      1        0.8     0             -                    0
1      2        0.3     1             0.8                 -0.5
1      3        0.1     1             0.8                 -0.7
1      4        0.2     3             0.1                  0.1
2      1        0.1     0             -                    0
2      2        0.5     4             0.1 (or NA)          0.4 (or NA)   
3      1        0.9     0             -                    0
3      2        0.5     4             0.9 (or NA)         -0.4 (or NA)
3      3        0.7     2             0.5                  0.2
3      4        0.6     1             0.7                 -0.1
4      1        0.3     0             -                    0
4      2        0.2     3             0.3                 -0.1
4      3        0.6     2             0.2                  0.4
```

Time here (in years) is the time since the previous testocc, and I want to find out what the highest score is within the past three years from a single testocc. Then I want to subtract the current score from that highest score. Each individual id is treated separately.

I am also hoping for two versions of this:

1. If the only prior value is >3 ago, I still want to subtract the current value from it (as shown in the desired output above)
2. If the only prior value is >3 ago, I want to put an NA (as shown beside the desired output in brackets above).

I figure I'll have to calculate all the pairwise times between all testocc's, make a cutoff at 3 years, and then subtract from the max value within that, I just have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just can't think of it. I know how to subtract the previous value or subtract the maximum value using data %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(...) I'm just not sure how I can subtract the previously maximum value, while applying the cutoff of time

Comment: I don't understand your desired output. It doesn't seem to correspond to your data or your desired behavior. Can you clarify. And here's a possible solution to the problem I think you describe: `data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  do({
    mutate(., 
           max = sapply(.$time, function(t){
             max(.$score[.$time <= t & t - .$time < 3])
           }))
  }) %>%
  mutate(difference = max - score)
`

Comment: Let me describe my output for id #1 to make it clearer:
0.8 - 0.8 = 0  (the 1st value for each individual will = zero, a subtraction of itself) 
0.3 - 0.8 = -0.5  (0.8 is prior to 0.3, is highest, and is within 3 years)
0.1 - 0.8 = -0.7  (0.8 is higher than 0.3, and is still within 3 years)
0.2 - 0.1 = 0.1  (0.1 is the only value within 3 years from 0.2) 
Each score subtracts the previous best score that is within 3 years of tests, creating the difference variable

Comment: in "0.2 - 0.1 = 0.1 (0.1 is the only value within 3 years from 0.2) ", why isn't the second row's value (.3) within three years? it has the same `$time` value

Comment: Time is the time since the previous test occasion. So test occasion 2 (score of 0.3) would be 4 years before test occasion 4. This is because test occasion 3 is 1 year after test occasion 2, and tesocc 4 is 3 years after testocc 2. Where 3+1 = 4.

Comment: To add context to the question: if someone gets their blood tested every 6 months, I want to find out at this current visit what their change in white blood cell count (WBC) is from their highest level of WBC over the previous three years, not just from their WBC at their last visit. This dataset is asking that question, but for every visit. What is the change in score value from the highest score value taken in the previous three years, at each test occasion

Comment: I still don't get how you get from the original data to your desired output. Why do scores change?

Comment: My mistake - scores should not be changing from the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to solve your version 2 using `dplyr`. You first group by `id` and calculate the running time from the time steps. Then you can calculate the maxima using the `do` syntax. Finally you fix the initial times and calculate the difference.

```
require(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(cumtime = cumsum(time)) %>%
  do({
    mutate(., 
           max = sapply(.$cumtime, function(t){
             max(.$score[.$cumtime < t & t - .$cumtime <= 3])
           }))
  }) %>%
  mutate(max = ifelse(cumtime == 0, score, max), 
         max = ifelse(!is.finite(max), NA, max),
         difference = score - max)
```